# Open url from terminal in chrome

Tags: pantheon-terminal, google-chrome, command-line, firefox

[image]

When I click on the link just echoed, it is opened in firefox.

Earlier such links from terminal were opened in chrome.

But then I made firefox as my default browser. Then on wards these links are opened in firefox.

But now I want to open links in chrome. I had made chrome as default browser.

Still these links are opened in firefox. How to solve this?

I am using  **elementary 14.04**.

I tried to recreate this in ubuntu. 
But there it is working fine.
When I changed to chrome as default browser, links from terminal are opened in chrome.

**What I have tried**

I uninstalled firefox.
Now the links are opening in chrome.

Then I again installed firefox.
Now the links are again opening in firefox

My Desktop Environment is panthaeon
Terminal is panthaeon-terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links from terminal are opened in your default browser. If you want to open it in chrome, make chrome your default browser...

Comment: chrome is my default browser. I had clearly specified in the question

Comment: Is it also in System Settings > Applications > Web Browser ?